# AHK Sending a TXT file as typed out text

Tags: autohotkey

am using AHK to publish boilerplate e-mail body texts in our company.  Our employees use various webmail, and other mail so managing templates is impossible.  So comes AHK.  We have created scripts to publish this with the details of the boilerplate within the body of the script, but it is difficult to delegate revision management when the script itself needs to be edited each time as the boilerplate text changes.  Is there a way to send the contents of a Text file, i.e. "bp..pins.txt" as a keyboard input verses placing all the boilerplate text within the script?

Btw: We use Dropbox to sync scripts across users computers.

Comment: Please try and post a example of the code you use.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is to simply use the command [FileRead](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileRead.htm)

```
FileSelectFile, path

::doit:: ; hotstring type "doit" to activate
FileRead, FileContent, %path%
Sendinput %FileContent%
return
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Do realize that SendInput has limitations.  If you send enough text, it will buffer in the keyboard buffer and show up on the screen much slower than expected.  It won't take more than a paragraph for the SendInput to end up being slower than a manual cut and paste.

I recommend reading the file into the clipboard and pasting it instead:

```
FileSelectFile, path

::doit:: ; hotstring type "doit" to activate
FileRead, FileContent, %path%
Clipboard := FileContent
SendInput ^v
return
```

Comment: This sounds good.  Been traveling and not able to code it yet.  Will give it a try next week and post the results.